# Docker-stack. Forcing docker stack services to use ipv4

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I would like to have a service being deployed as part of a docker stack to listen on ipv4.
Currently the docker stack deployed service (rabbitmq) is listening on ipv6, I would like to have it listen via ipv4.
The section of docker compose .yaml file that I using to deploy the docker stack as the following yaml section.

```
    rabbitmq-3-11-0:
      #image: rabbitmq:3.11.0-management
      image: "127.0.0.1:5000/bcl-sdv-rabbitmq-3-11-0:v0.1"
      ports:
        -
          "0.0.0.0:5672:5672/tcp"
        -
          "0.0.0.0:15672:15672/tcp" #15672: HTTP API clients, management UI and rabbitmqadmin (only if the management plugin is enabled)
```

On deployment of the docker stack, the "rabbitmq-3-11-0" service is deployed successfully.

To test IP connectivity I issue the following commands on the docker node.

```
ncat -w 2 -v ::1 5672 </dev/null; echo $?
```

yields

```
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ::1:5672.
```

While the command

```
ncat -w 2 -v 0.0.0.0 5672 </dev/null; echo $?
```

yields

```
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 0.0.0.0:5672.
Ncat: Connection reset by peer.
1
```

The command

```
ncat -w 2 -v 127.0.0.1 5672 </dev/null; echo $?
```

produces

```
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:5672.
Ncat: Connection reset by peer.
1
```

The netstat command below

```
sudo netstat -tulnp|grep 5672
```

shows that the ports 5672 and 15672 are listening on ipv6.

```
tcp6       4      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      2527/dockerd        
tcp6       0      0 :::15672                :::*                    LISTEN      2527/dockerd
```

The command to determine the docker version below

```
docker info|grep Version
```

Outputs

```
 Server Version: 20.10.20
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64
```

The Linux version command below

```
lsb_release
```

prints

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
```

Comment: That error suggests to me that your container isn't listening on port 5672; it doesn't have anything to do with IPv4 vs. IPv6.  If you're using a custom image, what's in its Dockerfile?  Are you in fact deploying this using Docker's Swarm cluster orchestration service?

Comment: thanks "David Maze" see the outputs of the ncat command you will see that the "ncat -w 2 -v ::1 5672 </dev/null; echo $?" establishes a connection and remains connected while the other ncat command I issued do not.

Comment: The above service is begin deployed as part of a docker stack deployment. I use a command such as "docker stack deploy --compose-file=/path/to/docker_compose_file.yaml my-rabbitmq-prod"